# Magento checkout page redirect to cart page

Tags: magento-1.8

I am suffering a serious problems. The problem is that when i enter billing information, select shipping method and press continue button then it goes to cart page. But Cart is not empty. It should go to payment method step. I am used magento 1.8.1.0 version. When i click on continue buttom my ajax is running . I get the following error in console

"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://www.themeatboutique.com.au/shop/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/"

All things are working fine before 4-5 days.

Finally I found about the problem. The problem is that $this is not working in setTemplate file. Not Sure why it is not working 
So Can anyone please tell me the solution

Comment: Finally I found solution myself through coding. Ignore this question

Comment: You can delete this question if you wish it to be ignored. Otherwise you'll be inviting down votes because the question is overly broad.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most common cause of 500 Internal Server Error on a Magento page that was previously working is a minor typographical mistake that affects syntax enough to make the .php impossible to compile into op-code, therefore, impossible to render, therefore, impossible to serve to the browser.

On the checkout page, such an issue in any of the code that is collated into the standard onepage "pseudo-view" you're using could produce that result at that step. It sounds like all rendered well up to the step following shipping, so your syntax error is most likely in one or the other of those files that creates the view for those two steps, and is most likely in the one following the shipping method.

Look for the usual suspects, a single-quote / double-quote mismatch, a stray line of code missing a semi-colon, a nested array with mismatched parentheses, etc.

If it is none of these, check your /var/system.log and /var/exception.log files for clues.

It is almost always frustratingly simple when you find it.

Happy hunting!

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got the solution myself.